# Bash files open terminal when opened

Tags: linux, bash

This seems like something simple to do but for the life of me I cannot figure out how to do it. I would like all bash (*.sh, *.bash) files to open with a terminal to show their output in.

Comment: When you mean "open", do you mean when you execute the bash file? Or when you want to edit its contents?

Comment: I would like it to work like Windows does when you click on a bat file it opens cmd to display the output

Answer (score 0):

If you are going to run some script from GUI and be able to see its output you can wrap a target script into your own one. You new script calls `terminal`->`bash`->`your_script` and waits until it finishes and exits. In the script below change `./script.sh` to your script name and path.

```
#!/bin/bash
# Bash Menu Script Example

xterm -e "bash -c \"./script.sh; exec bash\"" &
while [ `pidof xterm` ]
do
wait `pidof xterm`
done
```

UPDATE:

According to these close popular answers you need to have two scripts in your case.

- [How can I make a script that opens terminal windows and executes commands in them?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/46627/how-can-i-make-a-script-that-opens-terminal-windows-and-executes-commands-in-the/46630#46630)

If you are going to run some script from GUI and be able to see its output you need to enable it.

From Nautilus:

[image]

And them when you click your script you will be asked:

[image]

From command line:

`gnome-terminal -e command`

or

`xterm -e command`

or

`konsole -e command`

or

`terminal -e command`

To make the terminal stay when the command exits:

In konsole there is a --noclose flag.

In xterm, there is a -hold flag.

In gnome-terminal, go to Edit -> Profile Preferences -> Title. Click the Command tab. Select Hold the terminal from the drop-down menu labelled When command exits.

[image]

You should create a new profile for that and execute with

`gnome-terminal --window-with-profile=NAMEOFTHEPROFILE -e command`

Comment: This would require me to 2 bash files, no?

Comment: I assumed you have some and you are experiencing issues with running them. Writing in one script is a different matter, but you didn't say.

Comment: I would like bash files to open in terminal like Windows does, that way I may see there output

Comment: Again, are you going to write yours own scripts or run some already existed? Lust let me know, I will try to improve my answer.

Comment: I would like to write my own.

Comment: see please my updated answer.

Comment: I am using KDE not Unity